# How to apply a property (minHeight) to all TextViews with styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, styles, android-styles

I need that all the textviews of my app have a minHeight.

I tried with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F00</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">30dp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

But it's not working, it's ignoring minHeight, but textColor works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you somehow `overriding` the `minHeight` by something else in the xml? Something like, `android:layout_height=""` or `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. The style you have above should work, unless the layout_height is being overridden in the actual xml file where you are using it.

Comment: @theThapa of course I'm setting layou_height, but, then, what should I put in layout_height? theoricaly minHeight doesn't affect layout_height, it only specifies the minimum value for height.

Comment: When we override some attribute defined in styles with different value in the actual view.xml file, then the later one gets precedence. So, in the above case, if we define `minHeight=50dp` in styles, and we have `wrap_content` in xml, then it works. But if we have static values like, `35dp` or `70dp` in `android:layout_height`, then the value we defined in styles will be overridden. This is my understanding, please comment if I am missing something.

Comment: @theThapa if i dont specify it in styles.xml but in the layout or in java... it works, so the problem must be another

Comment: There could be something else that is going wrong too. I will test something myself and share if I find something.

Comment: @theThapa is right, if you want to use `minHeight`, then you must specify the `height` as a `wrap_content`. Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMinHeight(int). I have tested it and it's working in such a config.